# write stream in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing a mobile application with React Native. I have to write file to mobile storage and I choose react-native-scoped-storage library to pick directory where user want to write file, but this library return uri (content://...) instead of path. With content uri, I just can write a file has small size so I have to use writeStream method (rn-fetch-blob) or write method (react-native-fs). But both methods that support write stream are not support uri (content://...), it just accept file path to write. Anyone can give me a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I try sliding file and write the first part and append the rest. And it works perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).